# Facebook login returns generic profile picture URL

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook-graph-api

Well I'm using the code from Firebase and the in the user object the photoURL which being returned is [General facebook profile with no image](https://graph.facebook.com/3999140216772837/picture)

which is generic profile picture

```
Future signInWithFacebook() async {
try {
  // Trigger the sign-in flow
  final  result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

  // Create a credential from the access token
  final FacebookAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
  FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.token);

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  UserCredential res = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  User user = res.user;
  //create a new document for the user with the uid
  await UserProfileDatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
      user.displayName,
      user.email,
      user.emailVerified,
      user.phoneNumber,
      user.isAnonymous
      , {'helper': true},
      250
  );      return user;
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Facebook has recently changed the requirements for requesting profile pictures, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/#requirements But don’t ask me what that means in combination with firebase, because I don’t know. Check if they got any updates that take care of this change.

Comment: (The code you have shown does not appear to have anything to do with fetching the profile picture in particular, so if that happens elsewhere, you might need to modify something in that place then.)

Comment: To my knowledge if I res is a firebase instance photoURL is one of the properties of firebase user, no?
Because when I sign in with google account I do get the photoURL

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to display the Facebook profile picture URL after a successful login:

```
await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
final user = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();
Image.network(user["picture"]['data']['url']);
```

This code logs the user in via FacebookAuth, retrieves their user data, and displays their profile picture using the Image.network widget.